# Hive - Select keys with a particular value

Tags: hive

Is there a way in Hive to select all keys of a map that have a particular value? E.g. if my map looks like this:

```
{"default":1, "test":2, "experiment":1}
```

given the value 1, I would like to select (and then concatenate using concat_ws) the keys **"default"** and **"experiment"**.

If it helps, the map is stored as a member of a struct that is stored in the table I'm reading data from.

Comment: If the value is 1 why would `test` be selected?

Comment: sorry, I meant "experiment". Editing the question to make that clear.

Comment: did you find a solution?